# How to insert into a table using AngularJS and php backend

Tags: php, mysql, sql, angularjs

I have a view where the data of the clients are displayed from a table'clientttente ', displayed by a ng-repeat suffers from an array, and for each line that belongs to each client I have an 'add' button, this button must add each client to another table 'client', when I try this code, it generates this error: `undefined property "code"`, Where is the error please!

register.html

```
<div class="padding" ng-controller="RegisterCtrl" ng-init="loadClient1()">

<a class="button button-info"  href="#/ajoutClient" style="background-color:#6EB4DC;float:right">Ajouter un client</a>
<table>
<tr>
          <th>Code.Client</th>
          <th>Nom</th>
          <th>Prenom</th>
          <td>Ajouter</td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
          <td ng-model="code">{{x.CodeClient}} </a> </td>
          <td ng-model="nom">{{x.NomClient}}       </td>
          <td ng-model="prenom">{{x.PrenomClient}}</td> >
          <td><a class="button button-info" ng-click="insertClient()" >Ajouter</a> </td>        
</tr>
</table>
```

app.js

```
$scope.insertClient = function(){ 
      if(confirm("Êtes-vous sûr?"))  
           {   
           $http.post(  
                "http://localhost/deb/insertClient.php",  
                {  
                'code'   :$scope.code, 
                'nom'    :$scope.nom,
                'prenom' :$scope.prenom,
                }  

           ).success(function(data){  

           });  
         }
         else
         {
          return false;
         }
      }
```

insertClient.php

```
 <?php  

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  

 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));  
 if(count($data) > 0)  
 {    $CodeClient=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$data->code);
      $NomClient = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->nom); 
      $PrenomClient = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->prenom); 

      $query = "INSERT INTO client (NomClient,PrenomClient) VALUES 
      ('$NomClient','$PrenomClient') WHERE   CodeClient='$CodeClient'"; 

      if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  
      {  
           echo "The client has been successfully added";  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           echo 'Error';  
      }  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: use prepared staements not `mysqli_real_escape_string` to prevent SQL injection

Comment: do you want to INSERT a new record or UPDATE an existing one?

Comment: You can also [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear. Did you leave the question? Edit (ping), either that or @Jens 's answer did not solve the question. You will need to place a comment under the answer, and/or "ping" one of us here. I for one can't look at this question for any much longer waiting for an update/response to my comments.

Comment: Note: I retracted my vote to close (as unclear), seeing the OP has clarified what they wish to do.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `INSERT INTO ... WHERE` syntax. What you want to do is `UPDATE ..SET ..WHERE`:

```
$query = "UPDATE client  
  SET NomClient ='$NomClient' ,PrenomClient = '$PrenomClient'
  WHERE   CodeClient='$CodeClient'";
```

And as I suggested in my comment:

Use prepared statements not `mysqli_real_escape_string` to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Right. However, the OP states: *"it generates this error: undefinded property "code""* which is unrelated. Seems to be related to angular.

Comment: and their title reads as *"How to insert into a table"* - which to me, means just that; they seem to want to insert and not update. I placed a few comments under their question but they seem to not be present. And their *"Client ajouté avec succès"* is French for "The client has been successfully added", not "updated".

Answer (score 0):

I am submitting the following, since you are not responding to comments I left under your question. If you left the question during the time of your posting, you can read the following:

---

Seeing the title *"How to insert into a table"*, it appears that you want to INSERT a new record.

Your *"Client ajouté avec succès"* which is French for *"The client has been successfully **added**"*, which also suggests you want to insert a new record.

- Edit: The above (French) was as per the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44326781/1) before an update was made to the question.

[`INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) does not have a `WHERE` clause and that part of your code needs to be removed.

However, there is the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) if you wish to continue using INSERT.

If the goal is to update an existing record, then you need to use "UPDATE":

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Check for errors against the query using `mysqli_error($connect)`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: I m sorry to be late, and thank you for your answer, I will update my question as you suggest, but what I need is really an insert and not a update. because I want to  insert data selected from a table 'client into another table 'clientattente' and not an update. Thank you

Comment: @SalamSalam you're welcome. Remove the `WHERE   CodeClient='$CodeClient'` as I mentioned in my answer and along with everything else I wrote.

Comment: @SalamSalam however, if this is an angular-related issue, I won't be able to help you with that, since I do not have very much knowledge on that.